# SQL - Join 3 tables little confusing

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, distinct

I need a help about a little confusing sql query. I have 3 tables. Names : **article**, **category** and **category_article** table.

In my article table, there are 4 columns which are :

1. aid -> article id
2. py  -> Year of article
3. totalPoint -> point of Article
4. tc -> number of cited of article

In category table, there are 2 columns which are :

1. cid -> category id
2. category -> name of category

Lastly, in my category_article table, there are 2 columns which are :

1. cid -> category id
2. aid -> article id related with category

In the below, there are sample table inputs.

**Article Table**

```
______________________________
| aid | py | totalPoint | tc |
-------------------------------
| 1   | 2014| 30        | 3   |
-------------------------------
| 2   | 2013| 20        | 2   |
-------------------------------
| 3   | 2014| 50        | 10   |
_______________________________
```

**Category Table**

```
__________________
| cid | category   |
-------------------
| 1   | Surgery    | 
------------------- 
| 2   |  Enginering| 
____________________
```

**Category_Article Table**

```
__________________
| cid | aid       |
-------------------
| 1   | 3         | 
------------------- 
| 2   |  5        | 
____________________
```

My purpose is find this output with only one sql query.

> Category name, year, totalArticleNumber, totalPoint(desc), id of article(the most cited article at that year and at that category), citedTime (Top 20)

The example output is :

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________    
Category name | year | totalArticleNumber | totalPoint | id of article(best) | citedTime    |
________________________________________________________________________________________
   Surgery    | 2013 |     182            |    5234    |     312             |   22         | 
_________________________________________________________________________________________
   Engineering | 2014 |     189          |     5000    |      10             |    32        |
```

I can do this table with java programing language. Like first do some query and after that do it second query.

But i need to do it in one query.

I try to use `JOIN`  , `HAVING` , `GROUP BY` , `DISTINCT`  and anaother some sql stuff but i cannot succeed.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

For example if there are two article with same time cited value, they are shown together.
Like in first two column, the article 419 and 385 same time cited value so they both in table. 
There are two options for me.

First way -> Show only one article and limit 20. So in this way i can see 20 different category-year combination. 
Second way -> Show the same value timecited articles but i have to see 20 different category-year combination.

[image]

Comment: What does `citedTime` represent? And how do you determine the *best* article?

Comment: @McAdam331 citedTime is Times Cited of Article. That value of citedTime determines the article is best or not.

Comment: Sounds good, I'm typing something up right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky, because you're trying to do a lot of different things here. I would simply break them down and put them back together. First, if you want to `JOIN` all the tables together, you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM article a
JOIN category_article ca ON ca.aid = a.aid
JOIN category c ON c.cid = ca.cid;
```

Now, this will only show articles that are assigned to a category. In other words, if an article doesn't exist in the category_article table, or a category doesn't exist in the category_article table, it won't appear here.

If you want to get the total number of articles for a category per year, you can use the COUNT(*) aggregate function, and the SUM() function to get the total points for that category, and then group by category and year to get the amounts for that group:

```
SELECT c.category, a.py, COUNT(*) AS numArticles, SUM(totalPoint) AS totalPoints
FROM article a
JOIN category_article ca ON ca.aid = a.aid
JOIN category c ON c.cid = ca.cid
GROUP BY c.cid, a.py;
```

Next, getting the best article will have to be done using a subquery. I recommend focusing just on that subquery for a moment. You can write one query to get the MAX tc for each category and year, and then join that with your table to get all the matching conditions, like this:

```
SELECT c.category, a.*
FROM category c
JOIN category_article ca ON c.cid = ca.cid
JOIN article a ON a.aid = ca.aid
JOIN(
  SELECT c.cid, a.py, MAX(a.tc) AS maxCited
  FROM category c
  JOIN category_article ca ON ca.cid = c.cid
  JOIN article a ON a.aid = ca.aid
  GROUP BY c.cid, a.py) temp ON temp.cid = c.cid AND temp.py = a.py AND temp.maxCited = a.tc;
```

Once you have that, you can JOIN that subquery with the query above to show the best article information alongside the other group information.

```
SELECT temp1.category, temp1.py, temp1.numArticles, temp1.totalPoints, temp2.aid AS bestArticle, temp2.tc AS citedTime
FROM(
  SELECT c.category, a.py, COUNT(*) AS numArticles, SUM(totalPoint) AS totalPoints
  FROM article a
  JOIN category_article ca ON ca.aid = a.aid
  JOIN category c ON c.cid = ca.cid
  GROUP BY c.cid, a.py) temp1
JOIN(
  SELECT c.category, a.*
  FROM category c
  JOIN category_article ca ON c.cid = ca.cid
  JOIN article a ON a.aid = ca.aid
  JOIN(
    SELECT c.cid, a.py, MAX(a.tc) AS maxCited
    FROM category c
    JOIN category_article ca ON ca.cid = c.cid
    JOIN article a ON a.aid = ca.aid
    GROUP BY c.cid, a.py) temp ON temp.cid = c.cid AND temp.py = a.py AND temp.maxCited = a.tc) temp2
  ON temp1.category = temp2.category AND temp1.py = temp2.py;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f4f7/4) example. I am going to play around with how to use fewer JOINS, but for right now it should give you what you want and since your tables are indexed it shouldn't run too slowly.

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort. Like you said, i try to do lots of things in one query so this makes it hard. But there is something misunderstanding or maybe i cannot explain correctly.
In every year, one category should be placed in one time with best article.

Comment: If you don't understand, or something is incorrect, try to explain and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: Enginering(category) | 2009(year) | 55(numAritc) | 1843.13(totalPoint) | 385 (best article id) | 9 (best Article Cited time)


It shouldn't be another Engineering category in same year.

Comment: I hope i explain more clearly now, if not i can edit bottom of my question area.

Comment: Are you saying you're getting two rows for engineering in 2009?

Comment: Yes, i think that it is because of if there are two article with same times cited, they both shown. Maybe i can use having count or distinct for this problem

Comment: Maybe. If you can't figure it out, post some more sample data, except post sample data and expected results that *match*. That way, I can see what you want and I can try to recreate those exact results in an SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66366/discussion-between-batuhan-bardak-and-mcadam331).

Comment: Edit my question at the bottom side